# Jquery- this is a bit tricky to explain but how to add rowspan

Tags: jquery, html-table

Here's the table:

```
<table>
<tr><td rowspan=2>---A----</td></tr>
<tr><td>Not to this td</td></tr>
<tr><td>Not to this td</td></tr>

<tr><td>-----B ---ADD here</td></tr>
<tr><td>Not to this td</td></tr>

<tr><td rowspan=3>---C---</td></tr>
<tr><td>Not to this td</td></tr>
<tr><td>Not to this td</td></tr>
<tr><td>Not to this td</td></tr>
</table>
```

Essentially what I want to check is if a td has a rowspan AND if it does skip the next n rows depending on the number of rowspan. For example check the first td (A) and since it has a rowspan of 2 then skip the next 2 rows and check if B has a rowspan and if it doesn't, add rowspan of 1 and skip the following row and go on to C, since C has a rowspan of 3 then we skip the following 3 rows.

Comment: Which part do you have a problem with?

Comment: Include your JavaScript as well

Comment: Here: $("tr td:first-child").each(function() {
  if ( $(this).hasClass("HeadClass") ) {
   var th;   
   if ($(this).attr("rowSpan") !== undefined) {
       // attribute exists
       //th = $(this).attr('rowspan');         
   } else {
       // attribute does not exist
       $(this).attr('rowSpan',1);
   }   
  }
 });

Comment: Please add it to the question, this is hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will loop through all first childs of table rows, then checks if it has rowspan. If it does, it skips the next X rowspans. If not, it changes the rowspan to be 1.

```
$("tr td:first-child").each(function() {
  if (i > 0) {
    i--;
    return true;
  }
  if ($(this).attr("rowspan")) {
    i = $(this).attr("rowspan");
    return true;
  } else {
    $(this).attr("rowspan","1");
  }
}
```

Comment: How would this skip the X number of rows? Wouldn't the "return true" just skip it to the next row? and then add a rowspan to it which is wrong. Sorry I'm new to this and just started learning. thanks anyway

Comment: @user2036094 You're right, I didn't think about that. I suppose you would have to add some workarounds to make it skip the right amount of times. I'll edit my post to reflect this. Also, the adding rowspan is set off in an else statement, meaning it won't trigger unless the element has no rowspan attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, using this script:

```
    var rowspan = 0;
    $("table").find("tr").each(function(){
        var row = $(this);
        var firstCell = row.children().first(); // cell containing rowspan
        if (rowspan == 0){ // do not skip, determine new rowspan
            rowspan = firstCell.attr("rowspan"); // read rowspan
            if(!rowspan){ // not found, so add it
                rowspan = row.nextUntil("tr:has(td[rowspan])").length; 
                firstCell.attr("rowspan", rowspan);
            }
        }else{
            rowspan--; // decrease the number of rows to skip
            firstCell.hide(); // skip/hide this cell
        }        
    });
```

And here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ru6QY/).

*To improve the resulting html, you actually have to increase each rowspan by 1! A rowspan of two, does not define skipping two rows, but spanning two rows. That includes the row the cell is defined in.*

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a special class on the title td, you can do like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td.-main').not('[rowspan]').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('rowspan',2);
    });
});

<table>
<tr><td class="-main" rowspan=2>---A----</td></tr>
<tr><td>Not to this td</td></tr>
<tr><td>Not to this td</td></tr>

<tr><td class="-main">-----B ---ADD here</td></tr>
<tr><td>Not to this td</td></tr>

<tr><td class="-main" rowspan=3>---C---</td></tr>
<tr><td>Not to this td</td></tr>
<tr><td>Not to this td</td></tr>
<tr><td>Not to this td</td></tr>
</table>
```